# When a subclass calls super() with __init__(), where/what is the superclass's object?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, subclass

According to [Learn Python The Hard Way ex44](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html) and the explantion of using `super()` with `__init__`:

```
class Child(object): 
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff
        super(Child, self).__init__()
```

> This is pretty much the same as the `Child.altered` example above,
>   except I'm setting some variables in the `__init__` before having the
>   `Parent` initialize with its `Parent.__init__.`

So instantiating `Child` causes also an instantiation of `Parent`. But what/where is this instantiation? Given:

```
c = Child()
```

where/what is the `Parent` object?

Comment: `c` **is** *"the `Parent` object"*. A `Child` object is-a `Parent` object, that's the whole point of inheriting. In `Parent.__init__`, `self` will refer to `c`, the `Child` instance, as it does in `Child.__init__` (or, rather, the instance that will be assigned to `c` once all of the `__init__`s have run).

Comment: I'll use the comments for two personal opinions: First: LPTHW can be pretty horrible, I suggest that you use at least one secondary book or resource (e.g. [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/), [the python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/) or Python 3 OOP 2nd Ed by Dusty Phillips (last one is not free)). Second: Nice username.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so "Parent initialize with its `Parent.__init__`" does not imply that a separate object (other than `c`) is created?

Comment: Exactly. As I explained, you are calling the `__init__` method of your `Parent` on your new `Child` object. `c = Child()` creates only one Child object and not a separate `Parent` object.

Comment: @Pyderman is anything still unclear?

Comment: @timgeb a practical usage example, or justification for using `super()` in this way, would be helpful.

Comment: does the example make sense for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super(Child, self)` gives you the object which `self` is pointing to as an instance of the parent class of `Child` (which is `Parent`).

In the `__init__` method of `Child` you first do some stuff (`self.stuff = stuff`) and then call the `__init__` method of `Parent` *on your `Child` object* which `self` is pointing to!

You are not instantiating a `Parent` object explicitly, but because of inheritance every `Child` *is a* `Parent`.

> @timgeb a practical usage example, or justification for using super() in this way, would be helpful.

Sure, let's look at a simple example. Let's say you are building an application for a postal service. The service delivers several kinds of items such as packages, letters or postcards. Each of these items share some properties. To keep it simple, let's say they share the name of the receiver (in  a real world application, you would probably need more properties such as the full address of the receiver).

```
>>> class MailItem(object):
...     def __init__(self, receiver_name):
...         self.receiver_name = receiver_name
... 
>>> m = MailItem('Pyderman')
>>> m.receiver_name
'Pyderman'
```

This seems to work fine. However, our `MailItem` is far too unspecific. What if the item is a package? Then we would certainly care about its weight. On the other hand, if the item is a postcard, the weight would be irrelevant. Let's create a child class for the packages called `Package` which inherits from `MailItem`. Every `Package` object *is-a* `MailItem`, but it will store extra information about its weight.

```
>>> class Package(MailItem):
...     def __init__(self, receiver_name, weight):
...         # treat the package as a MailItem and call the MailItem initializier
...         super(Package, self).__init__(receiver_name)
...         # store extra information about the weight in some arbitrary unit
...         self.weight = weight
```

When we instantiate a `Package`, the first thing we do is to call the initializer of `MailItem`, because every `Package` is also a `MailItem`. This will not create another `MailItem` object, but call the `__init__` method of `MailItem` on our new `Package` object. In this example, we could have achieved the same thing by copying the line `self.receiver_name = receiver_name` from the initializer of `MailItem` into the initializer of `Package` instead of using `super`, but that would be duplicate code and go against the Dont-Repeat-Yourself principle.

Let's instantiate a `Package` to see the code at work.

```
>>> p = Package('Pyderman', 200)
>>> p.receiver_name
'Pyderman'
>>> p.weight
200
```

As you can see, the object `p` does have a `receiver_name`, because the initializer of `Package` calls the `MailItem` initializer via
 `super(Package, self).__init__(receiver_name)`.

At the risk of repeating myself, to make one thing crystal clear:
We are only creating one `Package` object with `p = Package('Pyderman', 200)`, not an additional `MailItem` object. Every `Package` object *is-a* `MailItem`, and Python will tell you so:

```
>>> isinstance(p, MailItem)
True
```

Of course, every `Package` is also a `Package`.

```
>>> isinstance(p, Package)
True
```

However, not every `MailItem` *is-a* `Package`:

```
>>> m = MailItem('Pyderman')
>>> isinstance(m, Package)
False
```

Think about it this way: every crocodile is a reptile, but not every reptile is a crocodile.

Comment: So really it's about avoiding duplicating the code in the parent's `__init__`? Sounds reasonable, if a little unnecessary (since it's only a single line of code).

Comment: And is it not the case (based on my understanding of inheritance) that we can omit an `__init__` function completely from the subclass, since the fact that it is inheriting will take care of the initialization? See http://pastebin.com/JkkSNHKu

Comment: @Pyderman Regarding your first comment: For this basic inheritance example, yes, but consider that an initializer of a parent class could have hundreds of lines. Regarding your second comment: Yes, if you want the subclass to do exactly the same in the `__init__` method what the base class does, you can omit the definition of `__init__` in the subclass. In our exaple, we must define `__init__` in `Package` because we want to do more than what happens in the `__init__` method of `MailItem` (set the weight).

Comment: I appreciate you sticking with the question until I had it clear, which it is now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not instantiation, *initialization* - carefully read the passage you quoted and you'll see it only mentions the latter. Initialization (sometimes historically also referred to as *construction*) is the process of building up an empty instance into a usable object of the given type.

`Parent.__init__` results in a usable `Parent` object; `Child.__init__` builds upon that to create a usable `Child` object. Thus, every `Child` object is by extension also a valid `Parent` object.